# How to update fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am making an app with 2 fragments that take up the whole screen and are managed by a viewpager and they both use location data, I get the location data by implementing LocationManager and the use LocationListener to check if the user has moved and needs new data.  Both fragments use the users location to display the initial data and both need to know if the user has changed location to display new data.  I use the following code to get location data and request updates:

```
    private void getLocationData() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("LOLWeather", "onLocationChange() callback received");
            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();                
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("LOLWeather", "onProviderDisabled callback received");
        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} ,REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LOCATION_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
    mLatitude = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LOCATION_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
    mLongitude = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LOCATION_PROVIDER).getLongitude();
}
```

My first question is I figure I can put this code inside each fragment and then onPause within each fragment I could do:
            if(mLocationManager != null) mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);

However it seems wrong to be requesting location data every time the user swaps from one fragment/view to another and also to be adding and removing the locationListener every time. Since they both use the location data I figured its best to place the getLocationData() method within the activity itself, is this correct??? If not how should I handle it, putting the getLocationData() method in each fragment???

My follow up question unless im wrong, which is where Im stuck, now that I have the getLocationData() method within the main activity when the onLocationChanged() method is called within the locationListener how do I tell the fragment that the location changed so it updates itself??? I originally pass the data to the fragment via a bundle but now that the fragment is created I can make a method within the fragment that updates it once it has the new data, but how do I let it know it has to update itself and give it the new location data???

Thanks.

Comment: You can use custom broadcast receiver to tell fragments about location update..

Comment: use `fused location` which provides best service you don't need to run it on background it gives you updated ` Location` its new and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since they both use the location data I figured its best to place the getLocationData() method within the activity itself, is this correct???

I think it is a good way to do it.

> how do I tell the fragment that the location changed so it updates itself???

You can send a broadcast when you catch your location update, and register a receiver to this event to update your fragment.

e.g:

When you catch the update event in your activity's method:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("action_location_updated"));
```

And then, in your fragment:

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if ("action_location_updated".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                // update fragment here
            }
        }
    };
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("action_location_updated");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

**NOTE:** It's better to use the action's string as a static final variable:

```
public static final ACTION_UPDATE_FRAGMENT = "action_location_updated";
```

Comment: how to get locaion at `onReceive` ?

Comment: you can add extras to the intent when you send the broadcast, which can contain the location data.

Comment: Question what is the right way to call registerReceiver within the Fragment since I get an error if I just write it like that, should I do getContext().registerReceiver??

Comment: *getContext()* gives you the context of the activity where you added the fragment so you can use it.

Comment: or use *getActivity()* if your target API is lower than 23

Comment: Ah, thats kinda my question I sometimes dont know when to use geContext(), getActivity() or this, and didnt know what the right one to use in this case was. I read an article here about the diference between them but still dont have it straight. Is it just dependent on target API? lower than 23 getActivity() higher getContext()???

Comment: I don't really know which one is really better but I prefer *getActivity()* to avoid to manage different APIs. Moreover, `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`, that's why you don't see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

The Right Way In my opinion
Is to put the function getLocationData() in Activity and from there send a Broadcast with the new position.

this is link with explain on broadcat.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Comment: Thanks this was the right answer as well but the other one was more descriptive and helped me get going, thank you!